# Не отображаются menu__items в hamburger menu

Tags: css

На Codepen все работает. Даже переносил другой гамбургер с другого сайта - тоже не работает. Кнопка нажимается, меню выдвигается, анимация есть, но menu__items нет

```css
#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 105%;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  outline: none;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0);
  outline: none;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  outline: none;
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.menu__btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #616161;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition-duration: .25s;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Open Sans Semi Bold;
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: 1s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
  outline: none;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu__btn" for="menu__toggle">
                  <span></span>
                </label>
  <ul class="menu__box">
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://imgur.com/zkaS2kW

Comment: Если воспроизвести ваш код на этом сайте - то всё работает. Скорее всего проблема кроется в вашем сайте. Я конечно не ванга, мне мне почему-то кажется, что основной цвет текста вашего сайта - `#fff`, из-за чего `menu__item` и не видать.

Comment: проблема в коде HTML скорее всего. Я все пересмотрел, но так и не понял как пофиксить проблему

Comment: https://codepen.io/enygf/pen/qBbPYRj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите сами, у вас [codepen](https://codepen.io/enygf/pen/qBbPYRj), в CSS, на строке 142-144 идёт такой код

```
ul > li {
  display: none;
}
```

Из-за этого кода и не видно ваших с `menu__items`.

Чтобы всё заработало, вам нужно изменить состояние `ul > li` на `display: block;` когда открывается меню

```
#menu__toggle:checked ~ ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: точно, как я не заметил сам то. Спасибо